# Right Management on the Document sync between SharePoint and OneDrive for bussiness

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, access, onedrive-for-business, access-rights

We recently adopt BYOD in our organization.  Now requirement is that if there is a document in SharePoint (on prem) with **Read only** permission and user sync it to his/her laptop or any mobile device with One Drive for business. After sync he/she would be able to share it, edit it etc....

We want to restrict user, so that even after syncing the document he/she can only be able to read the document but would not able to do other action with that document!!!
 Azure RMS is a solutions for it...  but is that possible within SharePoint itself !
Does any one have any suggestion for it !!

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no functionality to allow this built in to SharePoint. If you only use SharePoint, then once somebody takes a copy of a document out of it, then they can do whatever they like.

For office documents, you could consider using some of the built in mechanisms in office. You can either password protect a document to make it read-only without the password, mark it final and read-only, or use digital signatures. But these all have their drawbacks.

Comment: for office document, is there any built in functionality that use Windows authentication to open the document !!